# Français pour "get off scot-free"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

En anglais il existe le terme "get off scot-free", qui veut dire que quelqu'un échappe sans punition quand il a commis une faute.  Existe-t-il une phrase semblable en français?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Le plus proche que je vois est « il est sorti blanc de l'affaire ». Ça a à la fois le même sens et un niveau de langue similaire à « *he got off scot-free* ».

Ce n'est pas une expression très courante, on trouve plus souvent « il est sorti blanchi de l'affaire » qui n'a pas le même sens : « blanchi » implique qu'il a été accusé ou au moins soupçonné, puis innocenté, alors qu'on peut sortir blanc en n'ayant jamais été soupçonné. Dans ce sens-là, on peut aussi dire « il a été mis hors de cause ».

On peut aussi dire « il s'en tire impunément » ou « il s'en tire indemne ». Les deux sont plus formels que *scot-free* et un peu moins généraux. On a moins tendance à employer « impunément » lorsque le risque est de dégâts matériels, et moins tendance à employer « indemne » lorsque le risque est celui d'une punition volontaire et non d'un accident. Par exemple, on se tire indemne d'avoir traversé la rue sans regarder, mais impunément d'avoir commis un vol.

Une autre expression proche est « il s'en tire à bon compte ». Il peut y avoir eu une punition ou un dommage, mais celui-ci est beaucoup plus faible que ce à quoi on aurait pu s'attendre.

La base [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/get+off+scot+free.html) propose quelques autres traductions qui peuvent convenir dans certains contextes, comme « s'en tirer sans (aucune) difficulté » ou « être hors de cause » (qui implique que le risque est celui d'une punition de la part d'une autorité) ou « être épargné » (plus souvent alors tourné à la voix active : « *the crisis hit the industry hard while the tourism trade gets off scot-free* » = « la crise accable l'industrie mais épargne le secteur touristique »).

Comment: Un peu de pinaillage côté vocabulaire: "être épargné" *est passif* et non actif. Il n'y aurait "tournure active" que si on avait écrit "la crise épargne le secteur touristique" ou un exemple du même genre, avec "secteur" en complément et non en sujet.

Comment: @Circeus Ah oui, ce n'est pas du pinaillage. Je voulais justement donner un exemple à la voix active, et je ne sais pas trop comment j'ai fini par écrire une phrase maladroite à la voix passive. Merci de me l'avoir signalé.

Comment: Je n'étais pas sûr où la confusion c'était faite (et puis à l'échelle de la réponse dans son ensemble, c'est une petite correction ^_^)

Answer (score 4):

On peut utiliser aussi la métaphore :

> Passer entre les mailles du filet.

qui signifie « échapper à une répression ».